# How to make these four plots fit on page dynamically with no scrollbar?

Tags: bootstrap-4, plotly, resize

I am trying to make a dashboard with four demo-plots. Three are plotly and one is a word-cloud.  I want the four plots to resize with the page so that they always fit in the page and one never has to use a scrollbar.

But, no matter what I do, the height is too large and I have a scrollbar in vertical direction.

I think it has to do with the aspect ratio of the plots being fixed. But I am unsure how to dynamically set padding/margin to make the four plots fit on the screen.

Any help is appreciated!

HTML

```html
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block content %}

    <!-- HTML structure for Plots -->
    <div id="dashboard" class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">
                    <h4 class="card-title">Bar Plot</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div id="bar-plot" class="plot"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">
                    <h4 class="card-title">Line Plot</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div id="line-plot" class="plot"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">
                    <h4 class="card-title">Dot Plot</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div id="dot-plot" class="plot"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">
                    <h4 class="card-title">Word Cloud</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div id="word-cloud" class="plot"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    {% block scripts %}
        <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3-cloud/1.2.5/d3.layout.cloud.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
        <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/dashboard.js') }}"></script>
    {% endblock %}

{% endblock %}
```

Javascript:

```js
function renderWordCloud(width, height) {
    const words = ["Hello", "world", "normally", "you", "want", "more", "words", "than", "this"];
    const layout = d3.layout.cloud()
        .size([width, height])
        .words(words.map(function(d) {
            return {text: d};
        }))
        .padding(5)
        .rotate(function() { return ~~(Math.random() * 2) * 90; })
        .font("Impact")
        .fontSize(30)
        .on("end", draw);

    layout.start();

    function draw(words) {
        // Check if SVG already exists
        if (!d3.select("#word-cloud svg").empty()) {
            // Remove existing SVG
            d3.select("#word-cloud svg").remove();
        }
        d3.select("#word-cloud").append("svg")
            .attr("width", layout.size()[0])
            .attr("height", layout.size()[1])
            .append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + layout.size()[0] / 2 + "," + layout.size()[1] / 2 + ")")
            .selectAll("text")
            .data(words)
            .enter().append("text")
            .style("font-size", function(d) { return d.size + "px"; })
            .style("font-family", "Impact")
            .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
            .attr("transform", function(d) {
                return "translate(" + [d.x, d.y] + ")rotate(" + d.rotate + ")";
            })
            .text(function(d) { return d.text; });
    }
}


document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    // Common layout for all plots
    const commonLayout = {
        autosize: true
    };

    // Bar Plot
    const barData = [{
        x: ['Apples', 'Bananas', 'Oranges'],
        y: [10, 20, 30],
        type: 'bar'
    }];
    Plotly.newPlot('bar-plot', barData, commonLayout, {responsive: true});

    // Line Plot
    const lineData = [{
        x: [1, 2, 3, 4],
        y: [10, 11, 12, 13],
        type: 'scatter',
        mode: 'lines+markers'
    }];
    Plotly.newPlot('line-plot', lineData, commonLayout, {responsive: true});

    // Dot Plot
    const dotData = [{
        x: [1, 2, 3, 4],
        y: [10, 11, 12, 13],
        type: 'scatter',
        mode: 'markers'
    }];
    Plotly.newPlot('dot-plot', dotData, commonLayout, {responsive: true});

    // Word Cloud using d3-cloud
    renderWordCloud(window.innerWidth / 2, window.innerHeight / 2);
});
```